# Changing multiple elements with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

If this has been asked before I sincerely apologize. After around half an hour of searching I cannot seem to find one "best answer," and most solutions I have come across seem to involve JavaScript. While I am not totally opposed to JavaScript - HTML, CSS, and PHP are definitely my stronger skillsets. If this cannot be done without using JavaScript, I will probably need some serious baby talk. Here's my question:

I would like to change the background image of an one element as the hover state of an entirely separate element. Here is an example of how I would like this to work:

```
.some_element:hover {
    #some_unrelated_div {
         background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
    }
}
```

I hope that conveys a clear enough message of my ideal solution. Thanks guys.

Comment: You **might** be able to DOM traverse to the element, but I don't think CSS has a `parent` selector, so it's going to be VERY difficult.  In short, this _is_ a problem requiring a Javascript solution.  Luckily for you, a dash of jQuery and 3 lines of code will do the trick.

Comment: I don't think CSS will do the trick unless `#some_unrelated_div` is actually `related` i.e. is a child of .some_element and inherits the background from it.

Comment: CSS could be used if the _unrelated div_ is a descendant of _some_element_. I assume not since you say it's _unrelated_, but this can be accomplished with JavaScript. Could you post the markup so we can be sure the elements are unrelated?

Comment: making him install jquery might be making mountains out of molehills. I suggest a basic javascript answer.

Comment: @rockerest: There is no `:parent`.

Comment: @MiloLaMar: That's true. Sooner or later, though, the OP might need jQuery. And nowadays, it's becoming a standard.

Comment: @Blender I rescind my comment as I've forgotten how to write javascript myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS cannot accomplish this. CSS is meant to be read line-by-line and very quickly, so logic isn't something that should be done in CSS.

That being said, you *can* do this:

```
.some_element:hover #child_div {
  background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
}
```

***Iff*** your HTML is similar to this:

```
<div class="some_element">
  <div id="child_div">Hello</div>
</div>
```

This works because the selector matches the `#child_div` belonging to a `:hover`ed `.some_element`.

If you plan on using jQuery, this skeleton code will accomplish the job:

```
$('#trigger').hover(function() {
  $('#some_element').css('background-image', 'url("foo.png")');
}, function() {
  $('#some_element').css('background-image', 'url("bar.png")');
});
```

Comment: This helped a ton. You guys are right, I really do need to start using JQuery more. Thanks a million. RESOLVED

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in pure CSS but only if the element that you wish to change the background image of is a *child* of the element you are hovering over. For example:

```
#element1:hover #element2 {
    background-image: ...
}
```

If it is not a child then you will need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a comma if you wish to apply the same styles to multiple selectors. If you only separate them by a space, it implies that the latter must be a child element of the former in order to match. What it sounds like you're asking for is:

```
.some_element:hover, #some_unrelated_div {
  background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
}
```

Translation to English: All elements hovered over with class "some_element", as well as the element with id "some_unrelated_div" will have background image path/to/img.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript / jQuery for this, as it is an event triggered by a hover event on another element (like a menu button, etc).

CSS will style the elements for you, and you can use something like `toggle()` in jQuery to achieve this, but you ultimately need to create this functionality using JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
.some_element:hover #some_unrelated_div {
         background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
    }
```

this is the style that you want

Comment: This only works if #some_unrelated_div is a decendant of .some_element.  I got the impression that this was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve your desire. Here when ever user hovers the mouse on that element automatically jQuery Function will be called and after that you can put your own code to change the back-ground image url....

and if you want the reference then visit this link [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Care to...expand a bit on this? Linking to a website isn't really considered an answer, but more of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, CSS can't do this kind of stuff.  There MAY be a way to make a horrible chain of selectors **if** `#some_unrelated_div` is a distant child of `.some_element`.

Your best bet is including the jQuery library (like so):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then, in a script tag or an included file, write the following jQuery:

**[Untested, first-draft code]**

```
//this just waits for the DOM to finish loading
$(function(){

    //this selects .some_element and waits for the "hover" event
    $('.some_element').hover(

        // This is the function that executes when hover STARTS.
        function(){

            // this selects #some_unrelated_div and edits its CSS (an object)
            $('#some_unrelated_div').css({
                'background-image' : "url('path/to/img.jpg')"
            });
        },

        // This is the function that executes when hover ENDS.
        function(){
            $('#some_unrelated_div').css({
                'background-image' : [original style]
            });
        }
    );
})
```

Comment: No horrible chain  of selectors is needed. `foo bar` matches *any* `bar` that is a descendant of `foo`.

Comment: @Blender You're right.  I was getting my CSS scenarios mixed up, but all of the ones that would need a horrible chain wouldn't even work any way.

Comment: Try adding a second callback to your `hover`. You have to swap the image back somehow.

Comment: @Blender Woops thanks.  I guess this could use a variable to store the original background, but I think that might be a little too much for right now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could also do this with CSS.

But that's only possible if you have the div's somehow as adjacents.

I made you a JS-Fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5rz6/)

The key part is this:

```
#hoveredDiv:hover ~ div > #target
{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Here is the link to the w3c Specs about the ~-Selector: [Click me](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use javascript or jQuery to achive this.

However there is a workaround to achieve only using css. And that is to use parent-child element relationship.

let us assume div2 is inside div1
so you will need to add css as

- `#div1:hover #div2 {background-color:#F00}`

If you don't want the div2 to look like inside div1 then you can add position:absulute to it. As below:

- `#div1 {position:relative; width:100px; height:100px}`
- `#div2 {position:absolute; top:0; left:200px; height:100px}`

But I will always like to use jQuery to do this.